# Two-column nomenclature too long

Tags: longtable, multicol, mdframed, framed, nomenclature

I'm writing a research paper and have a rather long nomenclature that I want to put in a frame that spans as many pages as needed. However, when I try to do this, the nomenclature overflows at the bottom of the page and does not break to continue on the next.

The research paper is formatted in two columns, and I would therefore also like my nomenclature to be formatted in two columns.

I have tried using `supertabular`, `mdframed` and `longtable`, but I can't seem to get it to work in combination with the long nomenclature. Anyone that has a good idea on how this could be done?

Here is my code as is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\newcommand{\qforall}{\quad \forall}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{multicol} % Multiple columns environment
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{\item[\textbf{Sets}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{V}}{\item[\textbf{Parameters}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{Decision Variables}]}{}}}
}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip} % Baseline skip between items
\renewcommand*\nompreamble{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand*\nompostamble{\end{multicols}}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}


\begin{table*}[!htp]
\footnotesize
\begin{framed}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$i$}{Index $i$ specifies each of the different alternative fuels (with their corresponding engine type).}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$ACF_{vc,i}$}{Annual cash flow of vessel employing fuel $i$ on voyage charter.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$R_{tc}$}{Annual time charter revenue earned by vessel, in USD.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$R_{vc,i}$}{Annual voyage charter revenue earned by vessel employing fuel $i$ after cargo handling and terminal operating cost cost revenue share, in USD.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{voyage,i}$}{Annual voyage expenses of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{running,i}$}{Annual running expenses of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{capital,i}$}{Annual capital expenses of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{port,i}$}{Annual port charges of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{canal,i}$}{Annual canal dues of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{fuel,i}$}{Annual fuel cost of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{crew,i}$}{Annual crew expenses of vessel employing fuel $i$.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{stores}$}{Annual stores expenses.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{r\&m:h\&a}$}{Annual expenses for repairs and maintenance of hull and machinery.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{eOPEX,i}$}{Annual expenses for engine OPEX, including repairs, maintenance and lubricants for engine of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{insurance,i}$}{Annual total insurance expenses dependent on each fuel type.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{admin,i}$}{Annual administrative expenses of vessel employing fuel $i$.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{purchase,i} $}{One-time capital expense for purchase of vessel. Only contains shipowner's equity contribution, not debt. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$ C_{interest,i} $}{Annual interest expense over the remaining debt portion of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$ C_{principal,i} $}{Annual principal payment of vessel employing fuel $i$.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$ C_{bullet,i} $}{Bullet debt to be paid at the end of the loan term. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$ C_{dd,i} $}{Dry docking expense of vessel employing fuel $i$ at the end of each dry dock interval. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$ C_{ss,i} $}{Special survey expense of vessel employing fuel $i$ at the end of each special survey interval. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$ C_{scrap} $}{Scrapping income received upon the end of the vessel's lifetime.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$i$}{Index $i$ specifies each of the different alternative fuels (with their corresponding engine type).}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{voyage,i}$}{Annual voyage expenses of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{port,i}$}{Annual port charges of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{canal,i}$}{Annual canal dues of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{fuel,i}$}{Annual fuel cost of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{GHG,i}$}{Annual greenhouse gas emission cost of vessel employing fuel $i$. Only applicable under regulatory scenario employing market based measures. Further elaborated in section \ref{sec:scenarios}.  }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$GT$}{Vessel gross tonnage. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$c_{GT}$}{Port charges per gross tonnage charged by ports. Expressed in US dollar per gross tonnage (\$/GT). }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$c_{ce,NP}$}{Canal dues per New Panama canal exit including towage. Expressed in US dollar per canal exit (\$/exit).}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$c_{ce,S}$}{Canal dues per Suez canal exit including towage. Expressed in US dollar per canal exit (\$/exit).}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$c_{CO2eq}$}{Cost per ton of $CO_{2}$-equivalent GHG emissions. Expressed in US dollar per ton (\$/ton). }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$port_{a,i}$}{Average annual port arrivals.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$canal_{e,i}$}{Average annual canal exits of vessel employing fuel $i$. Counted upon exit of the canal. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$c_{mt,i}$}{Cost per unit of mass per fuel type. Expressed in US dollar per metric tonne (\$/mt). } 
\nomenclature[Vp]{$EC_{total,i}$}{Total annual propulsion and auxiliary energy consumption, expressed in mega joule (MJ).  }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$E_{CO2eq,i}$}{Ton $CO_{2}$-equivalent GHG emissions emitted per mega-joule energy by vessel employing fuel $i$. Expressed in ton $CO_{2}eq$/MJ. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$i$}{Index $i$ specifies each of the different alternative fuels (with their corresponding engine type).}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$FC_{total,i}$}{Annual fuel consumption of vessel employing fuel $i$, in metric tonnes (mt). }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$FC_{prop,i}$}{Propulsion fuel consumption of vessel employing fuel $i$, in metric tonnes (mt). }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$FC_{aux,i}$}{ Auxiliary fuel consumption of vessel employing fuel $i$ including off-hire, in metric tonnes (mt). Auxiliary equipment is assumed to be powered by the same fuel as used in the main engine.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$EC_{prop,i}$}{Propulsion energy consumption of vessel employing fuel $i$, in megawatt hour (MWh). }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$SFOC_{P,i}$}{  Specific fuel (oil) consumption (SFOC) at each percentage of engine power output per fuel type, in metric tonnes per megawatt (mt/MW). }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$ECF_{i}$}{Engine efficiency correction factor for fuel i in \%. For LNG and liquefied bio-methane, dual-fuel engines provide 9.5\% efficiency gains. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$pFC_{aux}$}{Percentage of propulsion fuel consumption additionally spent on auxiliary equipment. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$P_{vc_i}$}{Engine power output of a vessel employing fuel $i$ at optimal economic speed $vc_i$, in megawatt (MW). Regression formula produced with the Hollenbach Model provided by Prof. Koos Frouws (TU Delft). }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$t_{t,i}$}{Annual time a vessel employing fuel $i$ spends on transit. Excludes time spent loading and discharging. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$vc_{i}$}{Optimal economic vessel cruising speed for vessel employing fuel $i$ in knots (kts) as determined by the optimisation model of section \ref{sec:optimisation}.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$td_{l}$}{Transit distance sailed on leg $l$ expressed in nautical miles (nm). }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$i$}{Index $i$ specifies each of the different alternative fuels (with their corresponding engine type).}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{crew,i}$}{Annual crew expenses of vessel employing fuel $i$.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{stores}$}{Annual stores expenses.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{r\&m:h\&a}$}{Annual expenses for repairs and maintenance of hull and machinery.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{eOPEX,i}$}{Annual expenses for engine OPEX, including repairs, maintenance and lubricants for engine of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{insurance,i}$}{Annual total insurance expenses dependent on each fuel type.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{admin,i}$}{Annual administrative expenses of vessel employing fuel $i$.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$c_{cm,i}$}{Average annual cost per crew member including travel, insurance and other.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$cm$}{Number of crew members employed on vessel. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$c_{food}$}{Average daily food cost per crew member. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$c_{other}$}{Average daily cost for other stores. Includes additional outfit, furniture, furnishings, appliances, spare and replacement parts and tools. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$cd_{a}$}{Number of days per year the vessel is chartered on average. } 
\nomenclature[Vp]{$pc_{b,r\&m:h\&a}$}{Annual percentage of base vessel cost spent on repairs and maintenance of hull and machinery. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$P_{inst}$}{Installed power on vessel, in kilowatt (kW). }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$c_{okW,i}$}{Annual engine OPEX per kW installed engine power of vessel employing fuel $i$. Expressed in US dollar per kilowatt (\$/kW). }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{tv,i}$}{Cost of total vessel dependent on each vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$pc_{tv,insurance}$}{Annual percentage of total vessel cost spent on insurance. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$pc_{tv,admin}$}{Annual percentage of total vessel cost spent on administration. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$i$}{Index $i$ specifies each of the different alternative fuels (with their corresponding engine type).}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{capital,i}$}{Annual capital expenses of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{purchase,i}$}{One-time capital expense for purchase of vessel. Only contains shipowner's equity contribution, not debt. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{interest,i}$}{Annual interest expense over the remaining debt portion of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{bullet,i}$}{Bullet debt to be paid at the end of the loan term. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{dd,i}$}{Dry docking expense of vessel employing fuel $i$ at the end of each dry dock interval. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{ss,i}$}{Special survey expense of vessel employing fuel $i$ at the end of each special survey interval. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$d_{lt,i}$}{Total long-term debt of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$i_{rate}$}{Interest rate on debt. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$g$}{Gearing, otherwise named 'debt share' of total vessel cost expressed in \%.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{tv,i}$}{Cost of total vessel dependent on each fuel type. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_b$}{Cost of base vessel excluding engine and fuel systems. Base vessel cost is therefore equal for all fuel types. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{eCAPEX,i}$}{Engine CAPEX of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$c_{ckW,i}$}{Engine CAPEX per kW of vessel employing fuel $i$. Expressed in US dollar per kilowatt (\$/kW). }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$P_{inst}$}{Installed power on vessel, in kilowatt (kW). }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$rt$}{Repayment time for the debt as found in the loan agreement, in years. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$b$}{Bullet portion of debt to be paid at the end of the loan term, in \%. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$pc_{dd}$}{Percentage of total vessel cost spent on dry dock at end of dry dock interval. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$pc_{ss}$}{Percentage of total vessel cost spent on special survey at end of special survey interval. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$LDT$}{Vessel lightweight tonnage. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$v_{LDT}$}{Value per lightweight tonnage in \$/LDT. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$i$}{Index $i$ specifies each of the different alternative fuels (with their corresponding engine type).}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$RFR_i$}{Required freight rate per TEU-mile, in $\$/TEU-mile$.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{voyage,i}$}{Annual voyage expenses of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{running,i}$}{Annual running expenses of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$C_{capital,i}$}{Annual capital expenses of vessel employing fuel $i$. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$r$}{Discount rate $r$ represents the interest rate used to discount any future value to its present value. }
\nomenclature[Vp]{$TEU_{annual,i}$}{Average annual TEU transported by fuel type.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$d_{annual,i}$}{Average annual distance sailed by fuel type, in nautical miles.}
\nomenclature[Vp]{$lt$}{Vessel life-time, in years $Y$.}
\printnomenclature
\end{framed}
\end{table*} %% Nomenclature

\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names.bst}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

And a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of Nomenclature]

If you have any other questions please do let me know. I have been struggling for more than an hour now...

Comment: you have it in `\begin{table*}[!htp]` a table environment is always one-page you need to set it up to use longtable or another multi-page table package.

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle, thanks for the suggestion. I realise table* is not correct here, but I could not produce any reasonable output using the multi-page table packages mentioned. Any idea on how such a package should be implemented with nomenclature and framed?

Comment: unrelated but `$C_{stores}$` (etc) should be `$C_{\mathrm{stores}}$` or `$C_{\mathit{stores}}$` the default font is designed to make adjacent letters look like a product of one-letter variables and not like a word (as you can see in your image)

Comment: I don't really know the package but `texdoc nomencl` suggests (on page 10) that it uses longtable by default. so just removing the table* enviornment

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to help. I'm using table* to make two reasonable sized columns. If I remove that, I get two very thin columns within one column (does that make sense?), so in total I would be able to fit four columns on the page which is not what I'm looking for...

Comment: `\onecolumn` before the table and `\twocolumn` after. you can not split a `table*` environment over a page that is unrelated to nomenclature or longtable or anything, it is fundamental to how floats work they are unbreakable boxes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hi David, onecolumn and twocolumn works. They even fit on one page. However, now I can’t seem to be able to frame properly... The same problem comes up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Additionally, I intend to place the nomenclature on page 3, so switching to one column and back to two is not really an option. Doing so would split my text, which would not be an acceptable format. Ideally I’m still looking for a method to split a framed nomenclature over two pages in two columns...